# React Native "fetch" returning server response without the information

Tags: javascript, http, react-native

I am using react native to create an application to act as a website that currently exists (with a user interface that works on a phone). i am using the "fetch" method to send a Http POST request to get information from a web server. The web server sends a response but it doesn't include the response message:
[image]

I apologies that is an image but the debugger is not working for me.
The code used to send the request:

```
HttpRequest = (RequestURL, callback) => {

    var AdminLoginBindingModel = {
      usr: this.state.username,
      pwd: this.state.password,
    }

    fetch(RequestURL,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },     
      body: JSON.stringify(AdminLoginBindingModel)
    })
    .then((res) => {
      callback(res);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.setState({Response: "Error: " + error});
    })                       
}
```

The callback function in the parameters is just a function to change the state variable to display the information on the screen

```
ValidateResponse(response){
    this.setState({Response: "Result: " + JSON.stringify(response), 
        displayMessage: "Success"});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

The Request being sent is "https://mibase-test.mibase.com.au/members/api/startSession.php?usr=&pwd="
The server responds with a json object regardless of a correct login or not

Edit:
Changing the response to

```
.then((res) => {
      callback(res.json());
})
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get object from fetch response, you have to call `res.json` like following:

```
fetch(RequestURL, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },     
  body: JSON.stringify(AdminLoginBindingModel)
})
.then(res => res.json())    // HERE
.then(obj => callback(obj))
```

But it occurs an error because response body itself is invalid json format. It contains some HTML tags:

```
{"member": {"username":"","password":"","key":"***","status":"No"}}<br><br>Username: <br>Key: ***
```

Please check the inplementation of server.

---

EDIT: full code here

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")

HttpRequest = (RequestURL, callback) => {
    const AdminLoginBindingModel = { usr: "foo", pwd: "bar" }
    fetch(RequestURL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },     
      body: JSON.stringify(AdminLoginBindingModel)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(obj => callback(obj))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))                       
}

const ValidateResponse = response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
URL = 'https://mibase-test.mibase.com.au/members/api/startSession.php?usr=&pwd='
HttpRequest(URL, ValidateResponse)
```

Comment: I changed the server to only respond with the JSON object now

Comment: @CameronThompson It seems to work without error now. I added full code to my post.

Comment: I realised that I implemented your code incorrectly, using your method works perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 2):

`response` doesn't contain received data directly. It provides interface methods to retrieve it. For example use `response.json()` to parse response text as JSON. It will return promise that resolves to the parsed object. You won't need to call `JSON.parse` on it:

```
fetch(RequestURL,
{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },     
  body: JSON.stringify(AdminLoginBindingModel)
})
.then((res) => {
  return res.json();
}).then((obj) => {
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response and https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html for more information.

Comment: I changed my method as you said an now i get a response however the response is strange, i will edit my question to show the new response